# What can an Ethernet controller do when it has the "Power Management" capability?

Tags: ethernet, wake-on-lan

In a quest to get Wake-on-LAN working on my sony vaio, I got to read the `sudo lspci -v` output for the Realtek Semiconductor network card.

this is the relevant output:

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device 907b
        Flags:  bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
        Memory at c3404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at c3400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number <redacted>
        Kernel driver in use: r8168
        Kernel modules: r8169, r8168
```

My question is, what does the "Power Management version 3" means? and more importantly, where can I find documentation on what each capability means?

My system is arch linux.

Comment: Some degree of power management capability would be needed for Wake-on--Lan.

Comment: this may get you started: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch01.html